# Drupal 7 Browsing for Media from CKEditor

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

When using the add media button in the CKEditor in our Drupal 7 installation, and then clicking the Library tab, this is the dialog that we get:

[image: Browing for media]

What we would like is the ability to have filters etc. like in this screenshot from the Drupal Media Module page:

[image: View Library in Drupal Media Module]

So far we are unable to figure out how to configure the media module to have this extra View Library option.

We'd also like a similar function for when users click on the link button in the CKEditor.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot is from the (unstable) 2.x branch. The changes between 1.x and 2.x are documented [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/215218), one of them being:

> The Library tab in the Media browser is being converted to a Views-powered tab named 'Views library' enabled by default. The old library tab which is deprecated is named 'Library'. This means that Views is now a dependency for 2.x as well.

Bottom line, if you want that functionality you'll need to install the unstable branch of the module (although I really wouldn't recommend doing that, not a lot of modules get marked as 'unstable' so you should use any one that is with extreme caution).

I don't think there's any (existing) way to force the standard CKEditor link button to use the media popup, as it's provided by the CKEditor module itself. I think you'd need to write a custom plugin for both CKEditor and Media to get that functionality.

Comment: Thanks. That worked on our development site. Any ideas what problems we may see if we run with that unstable version?

Comment: 'Fraid not, I haven't tried that version yet. It might be worth looking through the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/media?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=bug&version=7.x&component=All) to see if there are any major problems